# BotFramework issue on Teams: Displaying of Video Card erroring out and causing dialog to freeze out

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, video-card

The following problem works fine in Emulator but fails in Teams.

A Dialog opens a QnA Maker Dialog.  Before the QnA prompts start -- it gets a VideoCard the first time a user goes to the dialog.  I initially thought there was some issue with using the QnA Maker on Teams -- but on a whim, I commented out the video card part of the step (or more accurately...all the below code) -- and now it works!

Is there an issue below that would freeze out the step (only in Teams) would be greatly appreciated! (any issues with VideoCards on teams?)

```
var welcomeUserState = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["DialogBotConversationStateAndUserStateAccessor"] as DialogBotConversationStateAndUserStateAccessor).WelcomeUserState.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
            if (welcomeUserState.DidSeeVideo == false)
            {
                welcomeUserState.DidSeeVideo = true;

                // WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall or with another dialog; here it is a Prompt Dialog.
                // Running a prompt here means the next WaterfallStep will be run when the users response is received.
                //await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"THIRD WATERFALL STEP 1: This is the first step.  You can put your code in each of these steps."), cancellationToken);

                var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
                reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                reply.Attachments.Add(GetVideoCard().ToAttachment());
                // Send the card(s) to the user as an attachment to the activity
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
```

Above code and project is here: https://github.com/andrewchungxam/2019ITBot/blob/master/MultiDialogsWithAccessorBotV4/Dialogs/ThirdWaterfallDialog.cs

Error in Azure portal: 
2/6/2019, 1:19:24 PM    Malformed Video card - Invalid aspect value

- I initially reported this issue here to see if there was a broader issue with video cards in Teams: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/5270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Video card is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#cards-not-supported-in-teams) by Microsoft Teams.

You can use [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview) which 
allows you to create modal popup experiences in your Teams application. Inside the popup, you can run your own custom HTML/JavaScript code, show an -based widget such as a YouTube or Microsoft Stream video, or display an Adaptive Card.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer Wajeed.  I think a solid "feature reques" would be a developer friendly cheat sheet that can cross reference Bot Functionality vs. channels (with a "Supported" and "Not supported" tag)?  I think a lot of people are designing / creating bots and then having issues later with features not being supported and error messages not being super clear.  Thanks a lot Wajeed.